# failing to receive email to subdomain from some host

Tags: postfix, subdomain

I recently set up a mail server in digitalocean server with postfix & dovecot. It works nicely for the main domain : example.com

I also set up a subdomain : verify.example.com

Sending and receiving works for both of them. Until I recently bumped into an issue with the subdomain. A user tried to send email at user@verify.example.com from his server. But I never got that mail.

Here is the /var/log/mail.log part:

```
postfix/smtpd[2627]: connect from gproxy3-pub.mail.unifiedlayer.com[69.89.30.42]
postfix/policy-spf[2635]: Policy action=PREPEND Received-SPF: pass (userdomain.com: Sender is authorized to use 'username@userdomain.com' in 'mfrom' identity (mechanism 'include:hostmonster.com' matched)) receiver=example.com; identity=mailfrom; envelope-from="username@userdomain.com"; helo=gproxy3-pub.mail.unifiedlayer.com; client-ip=69.89.30.42
postfix/smtpd[2627]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
postfix/smtpd[2627]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf lookup error for "user@example.com"
postfix/smtpd[2627]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from gproxy3-pub.mail.unifiedlayer.com[69.89.30.42]: 451 4.3.0 <user@example.com>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<username@userdomain.com> to=<user@example.com> proto=SMTP helo=<gproxy3-pub.mail.unifiedlayer.com>
postfix/smtpd[2627]: disconnect from gproxy3-pub.mail.unifiedlayer.com[69.89.30.42]
```

Notice that, in log file it says **user@example.com** but the email is sent to **user@verify.example.com**.Looks like the email 'redirected' from subdomain to main domain. I'm having this issue only from that user's server. For other users no such issue so far.

I've both MX & CNAME records set up for verify.example.com

Comment: Log clearly says, that you have wrong database parameters in configuration file(/etc/postfix/mysql*.cf). Correct them.

Comment: I get this access denied error when the user doesn't exist in virtual alias maps table. clearly user@mydomain.com doesn't exist but user@verify.mydomain.com exists in alias mapping table. btw, the same postfix config works for both main domain and subdomain from other users.

Comment: Please add the entire log pertaining to this email, there should be more.

Comment: @JennyD, updated the log. Replaced sender email with username@userdomain.com

Comment: @rezatxe, anyway, database connection settings in your configuration files is WRONG. It's "Access denied" by MySQL, not by PostFix itself. MySQL says that "i have no database user that you provided(UNKNOWN_USER), so i can't log you in, and can't provide you access to my databases". Verify and make this parameters correct.

Comment: Okay, I deleted CNAME record and added A record for the subdomain. And that fixed the problem. Can anyone explain this to me? The userdomain must be checking this and rewriting verify.example.com to example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not catching this at once, because this is the problem:

> I've both MX & CNAME records set up for verify.example.com

CNAMEs can only exist as single records and not combined with any other resource records. This is specified in [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), section 3.6.2.

The reason that email specifically breaks is found in [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5.1), section 5.1:

> That domain name, when queried, MUST return at least one address
> record (e.g., A or AAAA RR) that gives the IP address of the SMTP
> server to which the message should be directed. Any other response,
> specifically including a value that will return a CNAME record when
> queried, lies outside the scope of this Standard. The prohibition
> on labels in the data that resolve to CNAMEs is discussed in more
> detail in RFC 2181, Section 10.3.

When you changed the CNAME to an A record, you went from doing it wrong to doing it right, which is why it started working.

Incidentally, this is a prime example of why obfuscating your domain name is unhelpful. If you'd given out your real domain name, I would probably have found the error just by verifying your setup.

Comment: Thanks!! One more question: Is there any tool to do the similar checking (e.g. validating RFC 5321 standard) on my mail server for incoming emails?

Comment: I don't know of anything to run on your server, though it would be a great thing to have! But for the DNS part of the problem, there's http://dnscheck.iis.se which would have caught this if you ask it to verify your zone.